# How to ignore the value of an existing column stored in the database in an update form?

Tags: php, laravel

In my update form, the `passport` field receives the value of its record, but when I confirm the form the `unique` validation points out that this value is already repeated, and is only valid when I change the value, I don't want to do that I want this validation to be ignored if the value remains unchanged.

I use the same `JudokaRequest.php`  class in the `store()` and `update()` methods.

- `JodokaRequest.php`

```
    public function rules()
    {
       return [
          'passaport' => ['required','size:8','unique:judokas,passaport', new PassportNumberRule],
       ];
    }
    
    public function messages()
    {
       return [
          'passaport.unique' => 'The passport number is already registered, repeated passport values are not accepted.',
       ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Illuminate\Validation\Rule` so that you can add a condition on whether to ignore the `validation rule` for the given model.

**Usage**

```
return [
    'passaport' => [
        'required',
        'size:8',
        Rule::unique('judokas','passaport')->ignore(the instance of model you are editing), // if you are using the Route-Model Binding you can just refer the model using `$this->yourModel` 
        new PassportNumberRule,
    ],
];
```

Comment: ```'passaport' => ['required','size:8',Rule::unique('judokas','passaport')->ignore($this->id), new PassportNumberRule]```, apparently solved.

Comment: Have some problem if i leave the message ```passporte.unique```?